# Using password recommendations code

Tags: users

I've got a Drupal 9 site where I'm adding a form that will add a user  to the Drupal site and also to an external database. I'd like to be able to use the same mechanism that you see in the *Add user* form which shows recommendations for the password, and removes individual recommendation items as the entered password passes them.

Is there an API for using Drupal Core's code for this in my own forms?

Comment: This is the form element: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21PasswordConfirm.php/class/PasswordConfirm/10. I don't know whether the JavaScript tests automatically activate if you use it.

Comment: This is a broad recommendation question, probably off-topic and will be closed because of it. First step you need to take yourself is to find that piece of code in core that does it and then try to copy this to your custom implementation. If this doesn't work, find out why and show some code so we can help you move forward from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an API for using Drupal Core's code for this in my own forms?

Using the *password_confirm* form element, you automatically get the JavaScript code that does what you described. The function that adds the necessary JavaScript code is [`user_form_process_password_confirm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_form_process_password_confirm/9), but you do not need to call it, as that is a process hook that is automatically invoked for that form element.

```php
function user_form_process_password_confirm($element) {
  $password_settings = [
    'confirmTitle' => t('Passwords match:'),
    'confirmSuccess' => t('yes'),
    'confirmFailure' => t('no'),
    'showStrengthIndicator' => FALSE,
  ];

  if (\Drupal::config('user.settings')->get('password_strength')) {
    $password_settings['showStrengthIndicator'] = TRUE;
    $password_settings += [
      'strengthTitle' => t('Password strength:'),
      'hasWeaknesses' => t('Recommendations to make your password stronger:'),
      'tooShort' => t('Make it at least 12 characters'),
      'addLowerCase' => t('Add lowercase letters'),
      'addUpperCase' => t('Add uppercase letters'),
      'addNumbers' => t('Add numbers'),
      'addPunctuation' => t('Add punctuation'),
      'sameAsUsername' => t('Make it different from your username'),
      'weak' => t('Weak'),
      'fair' => t('Fair'),
      'good' => t('Good'),
      'strong' => t('Strong'),
      'username' => \Drupal::currentUser()->getAccountName(),
    ];
  }

  $element['#attached']['library'][] = 'user/drupal.user';
  $element['#attached']['drupalSettings']['password'] = $password_settings;

  return $element;
}
```

There is no need to add any specific CSS class to the form element, as that is already done from [`PasswordConfirm::processPasswordConfirm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21PasswordConfirm.php/function/PasswordConfirm%3A%3AprocessPasswordConfirm/9).

```php
  $element['pass1'] = [
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#title' => t('Password'),
    '#value' => empty($element['#value']) ? NULL : $element['#value']['pass1'],
    '#required' => $element['#required'],
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => [
        'password-field',
        'js-password-field',
      ],
      'autocomplete' => [
        'new-password',
      ],
    ],
    '#error_no_message' => TRUE,
  ];
  $element['pass2'] = [
    '#type' => 'password',
    '#title' => t('Confirm password'),
    '#value' => empty($element['#value']) ? NULL : $element['#value']['pass2'],
    '#required' => $element['#required'],
    '#attributes' => [
      'class' => [
        'password-confirm',
        'js-password-confirm',
      ],
      'autocomplete' => [
        'new-password',
      ],
    ],
    '#error_no_message' => TRUE,
  ];
```

To use a *password_confirm* form element, you just need to define the form element using code similar to the following one. (It is the code used by the User module for the account password.)

```php
$form['account']['pass'] = [
  '#type' => 'password_confirm',
  '#size' => 25,
  '#description' => $this->t('To change the current user password, enter the new password in both fields.'),
];
```

As side note, the *password_confirm* form element must not be confused with the *password* form element, which shows a single text field to enter a password, without the second text field to confirm it. It does not show the strength indicator either.